# How to increase space between one icon and another icon in material-bottom-tabs in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` in my react-native application. How can I increase space between icons and align them equally based on the width of the device.

`react-native: 0.62.1
@react-navigation/native: ^5.1.5
@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs: ^5.1.8`

**Current Behavior**

More space is left on Right and Left of the bottom tab bar, I am not able to align space equally between icons.
sample

**Expected Behavior**

I am using material-bottom-tabs and I want to increase space between one icon and another icon in material-bottom-tabs ( or ) align icons space equally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  activeColor="#f0edf6"
  inactiveColor="#3e2465"
  barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#694fad' }}
>
  {/* ... */}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

There is a prop like barStyle, you can add your custom styles for your tab navigator.
Hope this will fix your issue.

---

Comment: `<Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={this.state.selectedTab}
        activeColor="#fc8019"
        inactiveColor="#fc8019"
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF',width:width }}
      >
{/* ... */}
</Tab.Navigator>`
i used this style but no use

Comment: try using flex styles, don't mention width,

Comment: <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName={this.state.selectedTab}
   activeColor="#fc8019"
   inactiveColor="#fc8019"
   barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}
 >
   <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Main}
    options={{
     tabBarLabel: 'Home',
     tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
       <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />
     ),
   }}
   />
</Tab.Navigator>